# Prove a doubly periodic entire analytic function in complex plane is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I got stuck on this problem. So I really appreciate if anyone can give me some hint to move on. Thanks a lot.

> Prove that an entire analytic function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a constant function if $f(z) = f(z+1)=f(z+i)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

As far as I know, there're some famous theorems on how to prove an entire analytic function is constant, like Liouville theorem, maximal modulus theorem, identity theorem... But I still can't figure out how to apply those to this problem. I think about the dense property of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so I tried to prove that $f(z) = f(z+q)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then use the continuity to prove that it's true for $q \in \mathbb{R}$. But I can't prove that statement.

Comment: and for proving the Liouville theorem, use the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) : $f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2 i \pi} \int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$ which  $\to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ (since $|f(z)| < C$) when $n \ge 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions tell that the function is $(1,1)$-periodic and hence $$\sup_{\mathbb{C}}|f| = \max_{x,y\in [0,1]}|f(x + iy)| < \infty.$$

Comment: For the last statement, we can conclude that from the fact that $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is compact, so ${f([0,1] \times [0,1])}$ is compact, too. So it's bounded, is that right? Then we use Liouville theorem to get the conclusion. Am I wrong at any point?

Comment: @leducquang: that's correct!

Comment: So great and simple. Thanks a lot, @Giovanni :-D

Comment: @leducquang: you are welcome! btw, zhw's answer is pretty much the same: he was pointing out the periodicity in my opinion, which then leads to the consideration in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For all $m,n\in \mathbb Z,$ $f(z) = f(z+m+ni).$

Comment: Can you make your point a little clearer? Is it the same solution with @Giovanni?